# Anaconda distribution for solaris?

Tags: python, solaris, anaconda

Is there a Python Anaconda distribution (or something similar) available for the Solaris platform?  I am unable to find it here: https://www.continuum.io/downloads.

Comment: no, I don't think so.

Comment: Do you know of something similar that would work? Or do you have any recommendations for how to move forward with Solaris?

Comment: *Do you know of something similar that would work? Or do you have any recommendations for how to move forward with Solaris?*  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for my slow reply. The end goal would be to get a working version of Python + packages included in Anaconda distribution (i.e. pandas, numpy, scipy, scikitlearn, etc) working on the server that uses the Solaris platform.  Since I can't simply install the Anaconda distribution, I was wondering if anyone had ever gotten something like this working on a Solaris box.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official website of Anaconda there is none.

Now if you want to work some AI using Solaris, there are plenty of tools for working with Python and there are a lot of tutorials on installing and using on Solaris SPARC servers. Unfortunately big iron like SPARC servers as far as I know does not have official support for any Nvidia card, but they can serve for some work involving high memory usage.

https://blogs.oracle.com/solaris/python-on-solaris